# Using an instance variable of an object in a different class

Tags: java, class, object, instance-variables

I made an object called one using the Shape class, and I called the instance variable x1 for 'one', and set it to int x by doing int x = one.x1; and it works fine. But when I tried to do that in a different class, it doesn't work at all. When I tried to do that in a different class an error message shows up that said "one cannot be resolve to a variable." If anyone know what's wrong, and how to fix this, please let me know. Thank you.

```
package events;

public class Shape {

int x1;
int x2;
int y1;
int y2;
int width;
int height;

Shape(int x1, int y1, int width, int height) {

    this.x1 = x1;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.x2 = x1 + width;
    this.y2 = y1 + height;

}

public static void main(String[] args){

    Shape one = new Shape(4,4,4,4);

    int x = one.x1;

}

}
```

The codes that doesn't work:

```
package events;

public class test {

public static void main(String[] args){
    int x = one.x1;

}

}
```

Comment: You've pasted the code that works. You should probably paste the code that doesn't work so we can see what you're trying to do.

Comment: Variables in Java aren't global, their visibility scope depends on place they're defined. In your code, `one` is defined inside `main()` method and is not accessible nor visible anywhere outside it.

Comment: Where is the variable `one` declared?

Comment: So I have to initialize one in the class, make it static too, and when I call it in another class, I have to use Shape.one.x1 to call it. I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one works:

```
package events;

public class Shape {

int x1;
int x2;
int y1;
int y2;
int width;
int height;
static Shape one = new Shape(4,4,4,4);

Shape(int x1, int y1, int width, int height) {

    this.x1 = x1;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.x2 = x1 + width;
    this.y2 = y1 + height;

}

public static void main(String[] args){


    int x = one.x1;

}

}
```

A different class:

```
package events;

public class test {

public static void main(String[] args){
    int x = Shape.one.x1;

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the variables as public `public int x1;` if you want to access them externally.

However it is good practice to use getters and setters instead:

```
//things
private int x1;
//more stuff
public int getx1(){
    return x1;
}
public void setX1(int x){
    x1 = x;
}
```

**Edit**:

appears I've missed the point of the question, to actually answer it, you cannot access a variable outside of where it is defined. If you want to use `one` somewhere else, you will have to either create a setter for it, or define it in a broader scope.

If you must, I recommend doing something like i show above, define `private Shape one;` then set it in main `one = new Shape(...)` and add a getter for it `public Shape getOne(){...}`

then in the test class you can call `getOne()` and access the variables.

Comment: The error message was `"one cannot be resolve to a variable."`, so the problem is with `one`, not `x1`.

Comment: I believe OP's problem is of using `one` somewhere outside `main()` method

Comment: ah, completely missed that.